# Selecionar um ou mais Checkboxs liberar o botão de enviar

Tags: javascript, validação, checkbox

Olá Pessoal estou precisando de uma ajuda na seguinte questão:

Quando eu selecionar um checkbox o botão enviar não estara disponivel, mas se selecionar um ou mais está disponivel. segue o código:

```html
<div class="selecionar-todos">
 <input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="od" > SELECIONAR TODOS
</div>

<div class="grupos-imputs">
<input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="um"> UM
</div>

<div class="grupos-imputs">
<input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="dois"> DOIS
</div>

<div class="grupos-imputs">
<input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="tres"> TRÊS
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">ENVIAR</button>


/* SCRIPT SELECIONAR TODOS (FUNCIONANDO) */

<script>
 $("#od").change(function(){
            if(this.checked){
              $(":checkbox[name=tecnologia]")
              .attr("checked","checked");
            } else {
                $(":checkbox[name=tecnologia]")
                .removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });

</script>


 SCRIPT LIBERAR BOTAO QUE FUNCIONA COM INPUT TYPO TEXT (FUNCIONANDO) que tentei implementar no tipo CHECKBOX


<script>
 
 validate();
        $(':checkbox[name=tecnologia]').change(validate);
 
    function validate() {
        if (
            $(':checkbox[name=tecnologia]').val().length > 1) {
            $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

voce pode tentar colocar um id no campo input e desbilitar o botao da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="selecionar-todos">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="od" > SELECIONAR TODOS
</div>

<div class="grupos-imputs">
<input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="um"> UM
</div>

<div class="grupos-imputs">
<input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="dois"> DOIS
</div>

<div class="grupos-imputs">
<input class="form-check-input" name="tecnologia" type="checkbox" value="" id="tres"> TRÊS
</div>

<button id="enviar" type="button" class="btn btn-success">ENVIAR</button>


/* SCRIPT SELECIONAR TODOS (FUNCIONANDO) */

<script>
 $("#od").change(function(){
            if(this.checked){
              $(":checkbox[name=tecnologia]")
              .attr("checked","checked");
            } else {
                $(":checkbox[name=tecnologia]")
                .removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });

</script>


 SCRIPT LIBERAR BOTAO QUE FUNCIONA COM INPUT TYPO TEXT (FUNCIONANDO) que tentei implementar no tipo CHECKBOX


<script>
    $('#um, #dois, #tres').change(function() {
        if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 1){

            document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false;
        }        
    });

</script>
```

pode tambem usando jQuery

```
$("#enviar").attr("disabled", true); //para desativar o botao
$("#enviar").attr("disabled", false); //para ativar o botao
```

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado pela resposta, mas fiz o teste aqui e não funcionou, chegou a rodar o ajuste? minha impressão é que não seja .length que não se usa. agora não consigo lembrar qual usar.

Comment: modifiquei ele, tenta com esse

Comment: show de bola, deu certo! obrigado.

Comment: Prazer em ajudar